# i am not able to access my container from outside

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

```
cd8eeeb21b2d   flask-test-flask-app   "bash ./export.sh"       14 seconds ago   Up 14 seconds             0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp, :::5001->5000/tcp   flask-container
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  flask-app:
    container_name: flask-container
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
```

**Error that i am getting**

> curl -X GET http://localhost:5001/test

> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Am I crazy or did it originally say port 5000?

Comment: lol actually i tried both ways but still gives error

Answer (score 0):

You forwarded / published port `5001` of the **host** to port `5000` of the **container**.
Therefore, the one you have to access on your *host* is `5001`, bringing the complete command to `curl -X GET http://localhost:5001/test`.

Docker Docs about this: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports